# Effect on coil of two magnets moving in opposite direction

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

There is a coil of wire making up a closed circuit and two magnets. What would the effect be on the circuit if we simultaneously moved one magnet towards the coil and the other magnet away from the coil.

1. both magnets have their poles in the same direction.
2. the magnets have their poles in opposite directions.

Comment: It depends on which direction the magnets are moving towards the coil (sideways or into the coil mouth).

Comment: Also, remember the right hand rule.

Answer (score 2):

The effect would be determined by the resultant net magnetic field that is the vector sum of the fields of the individual magnets.

Comment: That remind me of [this joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/28dae1/two_guys_are_in_a_helicopter/) :)